# Disable css on cretin pages

Tags: html, css

I'm using an angular based website so each page uses the same global header.

I'm using

```
<link id="first_style" rel="rel="stylesheet" 
  href="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" href="#" disabled />
```

But it is messing up tables I have on other pages. Is there anything I can put in my HTML template to block this on a particular page. Please take into consideration that the HTML file that it is messing up has no header as the header is in the main index.php file. So what ever can be done to disable will have to be in the main body.

I had a look at the follwing

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
            document.getElementById('first_style').removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    </script>
```

Is there a way of instead of original attribute being disabled can i mark as enabled then replace the attribute with disabled using a mofified version of the above js. So instead of .removeAttribute('enabled'); can i replace with disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Create another `.css` file, copy the the code from `jquery.dataTables.min.css` and then remove the selectors that you want to disable. The only way you can disable a certain `.css` file is in for example `Chrome Dev Tools` but that's only for development, it doesn't apply on the production build, it's only intended for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i edited my first question please see above. Is the a way of doing what im talking about? Thanks